# Converting decimal to BCD

Tags: c, msp430, code-composer

I'm working on an assignment currently that uses a microcontroller and a circuit to display a decimal in binary, through LED's. I have to use three push buttons: one to increment, one to decrement, and the last to reset. I have my wiring and configuration complete. My code on the other hand has some glitches that I cannot fix with only an intro to C class under my belt. I am using Code Composer. Problem number one: My counter on the "Tens" section(MSB) does not stop at 9 but rather begins to display binary 10-15. The first four bits are the ones(right) and the second four bits, tens(left) ex: `1010 0001` but the max value is `1001 1001`. Problem number two: starting from zero if I decrement the value, the counter displays 95 rather than 99.
ex: starting from `0000 0000` decrement displays `1001 0101`. I tried using an if statement to make a condition for MSB to stop if greater than ten but the code doesn't run. Pretty much any modification I did to my code prevents it from working properly.

```
#include <msp430.h>

unsigned int dec2bcd(unsigned int num);
void delay(void);

int main(void) {
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;    // Stop watchdog timer

P1DIR = 0xFF;
P2DIR = 0xF0;
unsigned int c;
unsigned int count = 0x00;

while(1){
    if((P2IN & BIT0) == BIT0){
        count++;
        c = dec2bcd(count);
    }

    else if((P2IN&BIT1) == BIT1){
        count--;
        c = dec2bcd(count);
    }

    else if((P2IN&BIT2) == BIT2){
        count = 0x00;
        c = dec2bcd(count);
    }

    delay();
    P1OUT = c;

}

}

unsigned int dec2bcd(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int ones = 0;
    unsigned int tens = 0;
    unsigned int temp = 0;

    ones = num%10;
    temp = num/10;
    tens = temp<<4;
    return (tens + ones);
}

void delay(void)
{
    volatile unsigned int i, j;
    for(i=10000; i>0; i--)
    {
        for(j=3; j>0; j--){
    }
}
}
```

Comment: something to think about.  if this project is to increment and decrement a decimal number on a display.  you could keep track of each number separately if the ones variable after increment is greater than 9 then increment the tens and make the ones zero.  dividing binary to decimal all the time is a lot of overhead, esp for an msp430.

Comment: if you decreament 0 it wraps to the maximum unsinged int, but your dectobcd can only handle up to 99

Comment: What is the max count?,  How many BCD digits are there to display?  Can increment overflow?  Can decrement underflow?

Comment: A clean solution is to write a function to implement increment and decrement with the wrap-around behavior you want. The problem is not your dec to bcd conversion, but the default operator `++` and `--` of `unsigned int`:  `--0u` is 4294967295 (see the `95` here?) not `99`.

Comment: Properly debounce your buttons. That delay-loop thing is possibly too short and the buttons bounce. Provide all required information.

Comment: @user3528438: Nonsense, the MSP430 has 16 bit `int`! That is not a PC.

Comment: @chux max value is 99 and 8 bits are displayed. I thought it was clear but my bad lack of specificity?

Comment: @user3528438 Oh I see. Wow my logic only accounted for the max value without taking into consideration what the actual code will be doing. Thanks for the perspective change.

Comment: @Olaf looked deeper and found out the probable cause of 95, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you see 95?**

As mentioned by @Olaf, msp430 uses 16bit integer.

When you do `count = 0u -1`, count acutally wraps to `65535`;

```
unsigned int dec2bcd(unsigned int num) // num is now 65535
{
    unsigned int ones = 0;
    unsigned int tens = 0;
    unsigned int temp = 0;

    ones = num%10; // 65535%10 = 5
    temp = num/10; // 65535/10 = 6553
    tens = temp<<4;  // what's displayed is by tens is actually the lower
                     // 4 bits of tens, so tens is 6553%16=9
    return (tens + ones);// so the result is 95
}
```

**Why tens can to beyond 10**

Same problem, because your input is greater than 99.

```
unsigned int dec2bcd(unsigned int num) // say num is now 100
{
    unsigned int ones = 0;
    unsigned int tens = 0;
    unsigned int temp = 0;

    ones = num%10; // 100%10 = 0
    temp = num/10; // 100/10 = 10, or 0x0A
    tens = temp<<4;  
    return (tens + ones);// so the result is A0
}
```

**What you should do?**

In your code, limit the range to 0-99, you have the choice of either wrap-around (99+1=0, and 0-1=99)or saturation (99+1=99, 0-1=0). But whatevenr you need, you need to write it yourself: C language does not provide it.

Comment: This was extremely useful given that I knew there had to be a constraint of some sort. I modified my current code for dec2bcd `tens = (temp%10)<<4;` and it seemed to solve the first issue of displaying anything greater than 9 on the "tens" section. Now for the wrap around, is it wise to use an if-else-if-loop with the conditions for the wrap around?

Comment: @MarineUTEP I think it's OK

Comment: Here's my new code with the changes that make it function properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a strip of LEDs handy right now, but this shows how to work within a decimal range, but only convert at the point of output. The actual value is kept in the range `0..99` (note how the modulus is done when I decrement). Then you split the value into BCD nibbles, and combine them for output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int num, char *msg)
{
    int lsnib = num % 10;                        // decimal value of each nibble
    int msnib = num / 10;
    int ledpatt = (msnib << 4) + lsnib;          // recombine as BCD
    printf("%02X Expected %s\n", ledpatt, msg);
}

int main(void){
    int value;

    value = 42;
    display (value, "forty two");       // display 42

    value = 0;
    display (value, "zero");            // display 0

    value = 99;
    display (value, "ninety nine");     // display 99

    value = (value + 1) % 100;          // increment from 99
    display (value, "zero");            // should display 0

    value = (value -1 + 100) % 100;     // decrement from 0
    display (value, "ninety nine");     // should display 99

    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
42 Expected forty two
00 Expected zero
99 Expected ninety nine
00 Expected zero
99 Expected ninety nine
```

Comment: this answer sacrifises half the range of usnigned integer just to handle 0-1=99.

Comment: @user3528438 I am sure `0..99` is OP's range. Are you suggesting I work with `char` just because `int ` is more than adequate? Or do you think it should be `unsigned int` when `int` is adequate. Please explain.

Comment: Using modulus on MSP430 for wrap is a bad idea: too slow, too much code. Better compare&set.

Comment: @Olaf quite so, but that could save OP doing a delay to debounce ;)

Comment: @WeatherVane: Nice try, but the MSP430 is normally not **that** slow. Even my 6502 would be to fast for that ;-)

Comment: @Olaf that wasn't the main question. This is a general approach to handling ouput as decimal. And my 6502 is gloriously nailed to the wall!

Comment: Poor little thing! How did it deserve that? The deer was faster?

Comment: Okay, so the purpose of the modulus and the shifts were for extra credit on the assignment. As an EE student I strive to go beyond mediocrity, thus this code. @Olaf

Comment: @MarineUTEP: Using division on such a small MCU with limited resources is actually mediocre and typical for a PC-user. The better (and smarter) solution would be to use compares. Both, in terms of code size and speed with not less readbility if written properly. So, if you get extra points for the less efficient code, ... what does that tell about your tutor?

Answer (score 0):

is there any constraint on using this:

```
if((P2IN & BIT0) == BIT0){
    count++;
    if (count == 100)
        count = 0;
    c = dec2bcd(count);
}

else if((P2IN&BIT1) == BIT1){
    if (count == 0)
        count = 100;
    count--;
    c = dec2bcd(count);
}
```

Comment: first, calling /100 on msp430 is awfully slow so it's not wise to call it twice for someting this simple; second, this solution does not solve the 99/95 problem.

Comment: I think the existence of the delay function means that a slowing factor is intentionally imposed. But if that is **really** a problem, the assignment can become num = (num + 100k) % 100; where **100k** is the largest possible multiplier of 100.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. So I changed my answer. Sorry!

Comment: There weren't any constraints as far as I know. We are just learning the basics of Assembly and C Programming through the use of Code Composer. We are in the third week of the semester which involved learning Assembly commands. With this code I attained tunnel vision and didn't see beyond the scope of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Let us keep count in countBDC.

```
unsigned countBCD = 0;
unsigned count = 0;
while(1){
    if((P2IN & BIT0) == BIT0){
        count++;
        countBCD++;
        if ((countBCD & 0xF) >= 0xA) {
          // of course can combine these 2 lines
          countBCD -= 0xA; 
          countBCD += 0x10;  
          if ((countBCD & 0xF0) >= 0xA0) {
            countBCD -= 0xA0;
            countBCD += 0x100;
            ...
    // similar code for decrement
```

or use a BCD increment function

```
unsigned BCD_inc(unsigned x) {
  unsigned carry = 1;
  unsigned mask10 = 10;
  unsigned maskNibble = 15;
  while (carry) {
    x += carry;
    if ((x & maskNibble) >= mask10) {
      x -= mask10;
      mask10 <<= 4;
      maskNibble <<= 4;
      carry <<= 4;
    } else {
      carry = 0;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Is there a significant difference in using an  `unsigned variable` vs `unsigned int variable` ?

Comment: They are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code that has resolved the issues that I was having earlier. It may not be the most optimal but I managed to make it work. I added two if-statements that created the wrap around, and I modified the dec2bcd converter by implementing a modulus. The modulus in the "tens" section helped to get rid of the display issue. 
Thanks guys for helping me! Now I understand my syntax errors and thanks for showing me that there was a wider scope that I needed to pay attention to. Wish me luck and I hope I get the extra credit. Til next time.

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>

unsigned int dec2bcd(unsigned int num);
void delay(void);

int main(void) {
WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;    // Stop watchdog timer

P1DIR = 0xFF;
P2DIR = 0x00;
unsigned int c;
unsigned int count = 0x00;

//Here are some modified portions to create wrap around
while(1){
    if((P2IN & BIT0) == BIT0){
        count++;
        if(count == (99+1)){
            count = 0x00;
        }
        c = dec2bcd(count);
    }

    else if((P2IN&BIT1) == BIT1){
        count--;
        if(count == (0-1)){
            count = 0x63;
        }
        c = dec2bcd(count);
    }

    else if((P2IN&BIT2) == BIT2){
        count = 0x00;
        c = dec2bcd(count);
    }
    delay();
    P1OUT = c;

}

}

unsigned int dec2bcd(unsigned int num)
{
    unsigned int ones = 0;
    unsigned int tens = 0;
    unsigned int temp = 0;

    ones = num%10;
    temp = num/10;
    //I used modulus here to get rid of the improper display issue
    tens = (temp%10)<<4; 
    return (tens + ones);
}

void delay(void)
{
    volatile unsigned int i, j;
    for(i=10000; i>0; i--)
    {
        for(j=3; j>0; j--){
    }
}
}
```